# Null exception with comboBox

Tags: c#, combobox

I am trying to display data from list of string passed from Main Form into this form but the problem is that I am getting all the time "System.ArgumentNullException" even though the data are correctly passed to the newly declared list. Am I missing something?

```
       public LoginPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    WelcomePage secondForm = new WelcomePage();
    SqlConnection con;
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    public static DataRow dRow2 = null;
    public List<string> list = new List<string>();
    private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sql = @"SELECT * FROM [employeeAccount] WHERE [User Name] = @UserName AND [Password] = @Password ";
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtUserName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dt1.Load(reader);
            ListTransfer();
            InputChecker();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    private void LoginPage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = (@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\employeeDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
    }
    private void InputChecker()
    {
        if (dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            this.Hide();
            secondForm.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
            secondForm.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid input data!");
        }
    }
    private void ListTransfer()
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [Department] FROM [employeeTable]", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "employeeTable");
        //List<string> list = new List<string>();
        foreach(DataRow row in ds.Tables["employeeTable"].Rows)
        {
            list.Add(row["Department"].ToString());
        }
        Department_wise_Employee_Details dep = new Department_wise_Employee_Details(list);
    }
```

WelcomePage Form code:

```
    public WelcomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    HomePage thirdForm = new HomePage();
    private void btnContinue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        thirdForm.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
        thirdForm.Show();
    }
```

Then it gets to HomePage Form:

```
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    public HomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public HomePage(List<string>list)
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        this.list = list;
    }
    private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Department_wise_Employee_Details fourthForm = new Department_wise_Employee_Details(new LoginPage().list);
        fourthForm.Show();
    }
```

And from there you get to the form where the data for comboBox I would like to use.

Comment: It is really pointless telling us that you are receiving an exception if you do not also tell us precisely WHERE the exception occurs.  Also, you are missing an Assert( list != null ); statement in your constructor.

Comment: Also, you should use AddRange(list.ToArray()) instead of Add(list)

Comment: The exception occurs on the line with Add method for the comboBox.

Comment: Also, once you get past your null problem you will run into another problem: the argument to Items.Add() is an object, and this is the object which will be added to the combo box. You are passing it a list of objects. That won't work very well.  You need to loop through your list of items and invoke Add() for each individual item.

Comment: Well, there really isn't anything obvious apart from the fact that it is possible to create a new `Department_wise_Employee_Details` without initializing your `list` variable (you should either Assert that your list isn't null on the constructor or change `List<String> list` to `List<String> list = new List<String>`)

Comment: This seems to be an evolution of your previous question. But this combobox1 is initialized somewhere in your code? I mean, did you have declared and INITIALIZED the combobox1 (combobox1 = new ComboBox())  in the InitializeComponent method?

Comment: @Steve It's an argument null exception, not a null reference exception.

Comment: A stack trace would help, you know...

Comment: why don't you use a loop to add items?

Comment: I' ve just edited the code from the advices given but still with the same result. I also noticed that once I leave the overloaded constructor and get through debugging to the Click event the list is again null.

Comment: check overloaded constructor list , is it null?

Comment: Yes it is . Once it leaves the overloaded constructor and gets into the Click event it gets reset to null again.

Comment: Is the parameter to the constructor null?

Comment: So once it is placed on form and the code is generated in designer I don't have to decalre another one..ok. Yes same case as with the whole list...in the constructor is filled up with data outside is reset.

Comment: put the code of how do you send data for the form

Comment: most possibly it is because of the name of lists that are the same, change the name of one of them\

Comment: I thought that as long as you highlight with .this the one in the class the same names don't make any difference.

Comment: this.list = list is perfectly fine.

Comment: OK...i runed your code in visual studio(using a loop for allocating items to combobox) and it workes good.i think there is something wrong when sending data to this form

Comment: Therefore I updated the rest of the Main Form / LoginPage to hope that there will be the mistake made.

Comment: Every where when you want to show Department_wise_Employee_Details form you must sent list to it but in HomePage form you just show it not sending any data...

Comment: it seems that just from homepage you are going to go to Department_wise_Employee_Details ,if i am correct then you must send data from homepage to the target

Comment: I've just tried it but it didn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public HomePage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
List<string> list=new List<string>();
  private void ListTransfer()
   {
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [Department] FROM [employeeTable]", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "employeeTable");
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    foreach(DataRow row in ds.Tables["employeeTable"].Rows)
    {
        list.Add(row["Department"].ToString());
    }
   // Department_wise_Employee_Details dep = new Department_wise_Employee_Details(list);
   }
Department_wise_Employee_Details fourthForm = new Department_wise_Employee_Details(list);
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fourthForm.Show();
}
```

Comment: Added, but unfortunately without result.I will edit the above code to show you the change in the LoginPage and HomePage.

Comment: in fact you must make the list in HomePage and easily pass it to the Target page

Comment: but you are making the list in LogInPage.i

Comment: Yes I declare it it in LoginPage at set specifier on public as you showed in the code above.

Comment: fill your list in homePage and then send it to the target page.like the above  one

Comment: This really worked! Thank you @ako for your patience. Learnt another thing here...

Answer (score 0):

From your code snippets it is obvious that dep instance in ListTransfer is never shown. Therefore, the click event where you add the items is from another instance which does not receive the list parameter.